Butterworth filter vs Elliptic filter - artefacts and huge transient
I'm working on a project involving digital filters and DFT. I want to use sampled ECG data to determine the heart rate using power spectral density. While filtering the ECG samples (samples are from this database), I noticed a significant transient when applying an IIR high-pass Butterworth filter. Here's the code and the output:
clear;
clc;

fc = 360;
T = 1/fc; 

ecg_samples = load('105m (0).mat').val;
N = length(ecg_samples);
times = (0:N-1)*T;
ecg_samples = (ecg_samples-ecg_samples(1))./(max(ecg_samples)-ecg_samples(1));


fstopband_hhp = 0.5;
fpass_hhp = 0.6;   

hhp_butter = designfilt("highpassiir", ...
    PassbandFrequency = fpass_hhp, ...
    StopbandFrequency = fstopband_hhp, ...
    PassbandRipple = 1, ...
    StopbandAttenuation = 60, ...
    SampleRate = fc, ...
    DesignMethod = "butter");

hhp_elliptic = designfilt("highpassiir", ...
    PassbandFrequency = fpass_hhp, ...
    StopbandFrequency = fstopband_hhp, ...
    PassbandRipple = 1, ...
    StopbandAttenuation = 60, ...
    SampleRate = fc, ...
    DesignMethod = "ellip");

ecg_samples_filtered1 = filtfilt(hhp_butter,ecg_samples);
ecg_samples_filtered2 = filtfilt(hhp_elliptic,ecg_samples);

subplot(3,1,1);
plot(times,ecg_samples);
xlabel("time");
ylabel("amplitude");
title("before filtering");

subplot(3,1,2);
plot(times,ecg_samples_filtered1);
xlabel("time");
ylabel("amplitude");
title("butterworth filter");

subplot(3,1,3);
plot(times,ecg_samples_filtered2);
xlabel("time");
ylabel("amplitude");
title("elliptic filter");


As you can see the transient is not present using an elliptic filter with the same specs.
Why does this huge transient appear only when using a Butterworth filter with these specific specs? If I change the filter cutoff frequencies the Butterworth filter doesn't produce the transient, e.g. changing from fpass_hhp = 0.6; to fpass_hhp = 0.7;

What is the order of the Butterworth HP filter? Have you tried by turning it to SOS ?

@JuhaP - executing filtord(hhp_butter) I get 42. What's a SOS ?

SOS = Second order sections. se.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.iirfilter.sos.html
You probably go this routine: [num,den] = tf(hhp_butter); [sos,g] = tf2sos(num,den);

@minghierid I suggest you extract zero, poles of the IIR filter and use zp2sos, [z,p,k] = zpk(hhp_butter); [sos,g] = zp2sos(z,p,k);  and then you can use ecg_samples_filtered1 = filtfilt(sos,g,ecg_samples);

@AHT I get something that looks like a shifted sine wave with decreasing amplitude. I don't think is what I should get

@minghierid: you are still not removing the mean properly

@Hilmar how should I remove the mean? what's the correct way?

@minghierid: Did you look at all at the code I posted ? I used the most trivial way to remove it: x = x - mean(x). What about this do you find difficult or confusing ? I have no idea why you think your method would work ( since you don't explain the rationale behind it) but it clearly doesn't. How did you test or verify it ?

@Hilmar of course I did.I was not sure about my method to remove the mean, before the one I posted I used detrend() then in order to check if the transient was because the signal didn't start from 0, I tried this one which the signal start exactly from 0 with a normalized amplitude of 1.

Zero mean isn't the same as "starting at 0".

Here is what's happening
Your filter specification is unsuitable for a Butterworth filter especially with such a low corner frequency. The dead give away here is the filter order is which is 42 (which filtfilt() then doubles to a whopping 84).
The issue with such a high IIR filter order is numerically stability. Since the filter is recursive any rounding errors get amplified so you need sufficient numerical precision to keep the error low enough. For your filter even 64-bit floating isn't good enough. The elliptic filter works a lot better here since it only got an order of 8.
In general, designing a Butterworth using stopband attenuation and passband ripple is not a good fit. You are much better off just specifying the corner frequency and varying the order until you see something you like. Butterworth filter are flat in the passband have monotonically increasing stopband attenuation, so the concept of "ripple" or "min attenuation" doesn't really apply.
We can give you a few guidelines on filter design, but it is a complicated topic with some really non-trivial math underneath it, so I always suggest taking a formal class on the topic.

If you just want to do an IIR high or lowpass avoid filter orders of 10 or more. Revise the filter spec or change the filter type as needed.
Inspect your pole locations. Make sure your you have enough margin between the poles and the unit circle given your application requirements, data types, and implementation details.
Always implement IIR filters as cascaded second order section with proper zero-pole pairing and section ordering. Avoid MATLAB's filter() function or Python's scipy.lfilter(). Use sosfilt() or related flavors instead
Be aware that filtfilt() doubles the filter order, the passband ripple, the stopband ripple and moves the corner frequency. Make sure revise your base filter specification accordingly.
Avoid using filtfilt() directly. It's not documented which specific filter algorithm the function uses internally and it may change over time. Instead, implement it manually using sosfilt()' and flip()`
If your signal has any DC bias, remove it first (unless you need it), OR initialize the filter state with a proper DC solution.

If we really wanted to implement your super high order Butterworth manually this would look like
%% High order Butterworth using second order sections
x0 = ecg_samples(1:3600); % single input
x0 = x0 - mean(x0);  % remove DC bias

% BAD filter design spec
hhp = designfilt("highpassiir", ...
    'PassbandFrequency', fpass_hhp, ...
    'StopbandFrequency', fstopband_hhp, ...
    'PassbandRipple', 1, ...
    'StopbandAttenuation', 60, ...
    'SampleRate', fc, ...
    'DesignMethod', "butter");
 % get second order sections from filter
 sos =  hhp.Coefficients;
 % forward filter
 x1 = sosfilt(sos,x0);
 % backwards filter
 x2 = flip(sosfilt(sos,flip(x1)));
 plot(x2);



Thanks for your clear explanation, there are just some questions I have. 1) A filter is unstable if there are some poles outside the unit circle, why are internal poles important
if they're close to the circle? I mean. they're still inside.
2) You said " Make sure you have enough margin between the poles ..." but how much is "enough"? How do I know if there's enough distance between the poles and the circle?
3) And finally, why using sos filter is better than using designfilt()? What are the differences between these 2 methods?


Because what you do in  computer has finite precision. Every calculation adds a little noise that jiggles the poles a bit so the can end up outside the unit circle. 2) This requires a rather tedious and very complicated analysis. It's easier to just stay away from high order IIR filters in the first place and do a bit of trial and error. 3) apples to oranges designfilt() designs the filter, 'sosfilt()implements it. The main difference is betweenfilter() and 'sosfilt(). Again it's about numerical stability and error propagation. The difference in behavior is substantial.



cont.: The reasons require a deep dive that's probably appropriate for a postgrad level  class. At this point, it's not just the algorithm but also exact filter topology, pole/zero pairing, section ordering, gain staging, etc.


So I need to design the filter with designfilt() and then implement it using sosfilt() I got it. The code you wrote is about the high-order IIR filter, is there a way to design a Butterworth filter with the same specs but with lower order? You also said "Butterworth filter are flat in the passband have monotonically increasing stopband attenuation, so the concept of 'ripple' or 'min attenuation' doesn't really apply." so to design a Butterworth filter is it better to use butter(n,Wn) where I can specify the order and cutoff frequency?

I'm sorry, but I think would you really need to do is to take a class on filter design and analysis. It looks easy on the surface but there is a LOT of complicated math involved and hacking your way through there is unlikely to get you the results you want.

I'll do, as soon as I graduate. They introduced to filter this year so I'm still "exploring" and experimenting by myself, waiting to take a more specific class, but since probably It will take some time I'm trying to learn by doing. If you want to help me (or reply to the last questions), I'll appreciate, otherwise If you want you can also suggest me some references

Note that the designed Butterworth filter is of order 47 while the designed elliptic filter just has a lower order 7 given the same specification which is a known fact as mentioned here.
Keeping the same spec, you can incorporate the modification below to get a similar result after zero-phase filtering by the designed Butterworth filter
[z,p,k] = zpk(hhp_butter);
[sos,g] = zp2sos(z,p,k,"down");
ecg_samples_filtered1 = filtfilt(sos,g,[ecg_samples(end:-1:1),ecg_samples,ecg_samples(1:end)]);
ecg_samples_filtered1 = ecg_samples_filtered1(length(ecg_samples)+(1:length(ecg_samples)));

Here is the result


Thanks for the explanation. I have a couple of questions:

Why is the filter order so important? What does it mean in practical terms?
Could you also explain the code?

